# Почём мы пишем не «маливать», а «малевать»?

Tags: орфография

Почему мы пишем не *маливать*, а *малевать*?

Comment: А как вы думаете, почему?  Ведь у вас есть версия?

Comment: Какое-то орфоправило есть.

Comment: Может, из-за того, что есть глагол немецкий *mal**en***?

Comment: Есть, конечно. Вы сами не пробовали найти? Ведь это нетрудно. У Розенталя наверняка есть. Немецкий глагол? Но это же русский суффикс).  Выбор ЕВА/ИВА в грамматике и в орфографии.